# MYSQL - calculated column aliases?

Tags: mysql, column-alias

I want to have a SELECT statement name columns based on other column values.

Let's say I have a table with column names like q_1, q_2 and other columns like q_1_name and q_2_name

Right now we are doing something like

```
SELECT SUM(q_1), SUM(q_2) from mytable;
```

I'd like to get a result set with the columns named for the values in q_1_name and q_2_name

```
SELECT SUM(q_1) as (q_1_name), SUM(q_2) as (q_2_name) from mytable;
```

Any chance you know a way to do this?

Comment: A query cannot have "dynamic" column names. Just think about (1) for your query you are summing multiple records, which record would you expect the value to be pulled from, (2) in a non-aggregating query with numerous result rows, which row's _name value should be used?

Comment: If you need to create dynamic SQL, you have to do it in a stored procedure with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of source data and the resultset you wish to get? Also, please specify what task you're trying to accomplish. It looks like you've chosen the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simply alias AS

```
SELECT SUM(q_1) as q_1_name, SUM(q_2) as q_2_name from mytable;
```

or using a subselect

```
select t.q_1_name, t.q_2_name
from (
SELECT SUM(q_1) as q_1_name, SUM(q_2) as q_2_name from mytable
) t;
```

Comment: I don't want the columns literally named
  *q_1_name*
I wanted them named for the contents of that column.

Comment: You mean that  q_1_name is a var ?  ... if so you must do using dinamic sql server side